# Jquery fileupload internet explorer 9 загружает не по тому адресу

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

Есть одностраничное приложение с дивом, куда подгружается input, который будет передавать файл на web-api.
Подгружаемое содержимое имеет следующий код:

```
 $('#vps_scan_file').prop('data-url', 'my-url');
            $('#vps_scan_file').fileupload({
                    url: $(this).prop('data-url'),
                    method: "POST",
                    forceIframeTransport: true,
                    add: function (e, data) {
                        data.context = $('<button id="upload_button">Загрузить</button>').appendTo($('#for_ie'));
                        $('#upload_button').off('click').on('click',function () {
                                $('#vps_for_scan').empty();
                                data.context = $('<p/>').text('Загрузка...').replaceAll($(this));
                                data.submit();
                            });
                    },
                    done: function (e, data) {
                        /*Function after upload*/
                    }
                });
        };
```

```html
<input type="file" id="vps_scan_file" name="files[]" class="btn" data-url="">
```

К странице подключены jqury-iframe-transport, jquery-ui-widget и сам jquery-fileupload. Все работает в IE8-, для Chrome и IE10+ я использую другую технологию. Вся проблема в IE9 - он отсылает файл не по адресу 'my-url', а на главную страницу, куда подгружается содержимое. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел единственный выход (на текущий момент) - это отображать (если IE9) ссылку, при нажатии на которую открывается новое окно со страничкой, на которой с помощью метатэга эмулируется режим IE8.